# Django Admin - add collapse to a fieldset, but have it start expanded

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to make a fieldset collapsible, but start expanded?  When you add collapse to the fieldset classes, it gets the functionality but starts collapsed.  I've taken a look at the JS that shows/hides the fieldset content, but it doesn't look like there's anything in there to do what I'd like it to, so I'm assuming I'll have to roll my own.  Just wanted to check before I went through that effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[django-grappelli](https://grappelliproject.com) provides this as one of the features.  Here's the [documentation](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html?highlight=collapse#collapsibles) about "Collapsibles".

Answer (score 16):

admin.py:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', 'content', )
        }),
        ('Other Informations', {
            'classes': ('collapse', 'open'),
            'fields': ('slug', 'create-date',)
        }),
    )
```

templates/app_label/model_name/change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/model_name/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/collapse-open.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

static/admin/js/collapse-open.js:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('fieldset.collapse.open').removeClass('collapsed');
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: I adjusted the javascript to change "Open" to "Hide"

Comment: working in 2021 with $(window).on('load', function() {   instead of  $(document).ready(function() { ...

Comment: @RanjitChawla Thank you for the update. I don't use jQuery for a long time but [according to jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) `document.ready()` is still a valid way. Are you sure that change is needed?

Comment: @MuratÇorlu - its more to do with when Django Admin creates the collapsible. document.ready() fires before the collapsible is created, hence waiting for $(window).on('load' .. is required ..

Answer (score 13):

I know this is real old but I also just came across this issue. After thinking about it way too hard I found an easy solution which seems to get the job done involving 0 plugins or additional js.

Within fieldsets construct Add 'collapse in' rather than 'collapse' to class:

```html
fieldsets = [
    ('Start Expanded', {
    'fields': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], 
    'classes': ['collapse in',]
    })
]
```

Comment: Hmm what version of django did this work in? I'm running on django 2.0 and it doesn't work for me - even if I add the `in` class, django automatically adds `collapsed` class which collapses the whole block...

Comment: I believe I was using 1.8 at the time. Haven't upgraded so can't confirm or deny this no longer works.

Comment: nice one, since there's no need of extra libraries to achieve the solution.

Comment: no more on django 3.2. would've been my prefered solution ;_)

Answer (score 4):

Accoding with the [grappelli docs](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#collapsibles) only need to add "classes" : ('grp-collapse grp-closed')

for example

```
class EntryOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...
   fieldsets = (
     ('', {
        'fields': ('title', 'subtitle', 'slug', 'pub_date', 'status',),
     }),
     ('Flags', {
        'classes': ('grp-collapse grp-closed',),
        'fields' : ('flag_front', 'flag_sticky', 'flag_allow_comments',),
    }),
```

note: if you use grappelli version < 2.4 use 'grp-closed' instead 'collapse-closed'*
actually 'collapse-close' still is working but is recommended to use the new classes

Comment: Only this one 'grp-collapse grp-closed' work for me.  Tested with 'collapse' and 'collapse', 'open', none of them have effect.  The group is not even collapsable on click.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Setomidor answer, I'd like to suggest a simpler alternative that does exactly what you want (if Grappelli is not an option, obviously).

Create the template override as explained (`admin/(app)/(model)/change_form.html`) and **instead of removing the collapsible effect** for the "add" model case, simply **call the click method of the field-set collapser** (i.e. the small link with the show/hide text) to have the whole field-set expanded as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest hack I could find was to add a new class `start-open` to the fieldset

```
classes = ['collapse', 'start-open']
```

and then modify `static/admin/js/collapse.js`.

from:

```
    // Add toggle to anchor tag
    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.collapse a.collapse-toggle');
    var toggleFunc = function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var fieldset = closestElem(this, 'fieldset');
        if (fieldset.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
            // Show
            this.textContent = gettext('Hide');
            fieldset.classList.remove('collapsed');
        } else {
            // Hide
            this.textContent = gettext('Show');
            fieldset.classList.add('collapsed');
        }
    };
    for (i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
        toggles[i].addEventListener('click', toggleFunc);
    }
```

to:

```
    // Add toggle to anchor tag
    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.collapse a.collapse-toggle');
    // NEW: select toggles to open
    var open_toggles = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.collapse.start-open a.collapse-toggle');
    var toggleFunc = function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var fieldset = closestElem(this, 'fieldset');
        if (fieldset.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
            // Show
            this.textContent = gettext('Hide');
            fieldset.classList.remove('collapsed');
        } else {
            // Hide
            this.textContent = gettext('Show');
            fieldset.classList.add('collapsed');
        }
    };
    for (i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++) {
        toggles[i].addEventListener('click', toggleFunc);
    }
    // NEW: open toggles
    for (i = 0; i < open_toggles.length; i++) {
        toggles[i].click();
    }
```

Comment: Still useful in 2020

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into the same one and came up with an answer which can be implemented using standard django:

create file: admin/(app)/(model)/change_form.html in your templates directory to make your (model) of your (app) use that form file.

Add this code to the file:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <!-- Load superblock (where django.jquery resides) -->
    {{ block.super }}
    <!-- only do this on 'add' actions (and not 'change' actions) -->
    {% if add and adminform %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function($) {
                //Remove the 'collapsed' class to make the fieldset open
                $('.collapse').removeClass('collapsed');

                //Remove the show/hide links
                $('.collapse h2 a').remove();

                //Tidy up by removing the parenthesis from all headings
                var $headings = $(".collapse h2");
                $headings.each(function(i, current){
                    var str = $(current).text();
                    parenthesisStart = str.indexOf('(');
                    $(current).text(str.substring(0, parenthesisStart));
                });
            });                                 
        })(django.jQuery);                      
    </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

For more information about using django.jQuery instead of "regular" jQuery, see: http://blog.picante.co.nz/post/Customizing-Django-Admin-with-jQuery--Getting--is-not-a-function/

Answer (score 0):

So this one worked for me:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', 'content', )
        }),
        ('Other Informations', {
            'classes': ('wide'),
            'fields': ('slug', 'create-date',)
        }),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

With django 4.x, here is my admin/js/collapse.js
add **start-open** in class

```
'use strict';
{
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Add anchor tag for Show/Hide link
        const fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.collapse');
        // NEW: select toggles to open
        var open_toggles = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.collapse.start-open');        
        for (const [i, elem] of fieldsets.entries()) {
            // Don't hide if fields in this fieldset have errors
            if (elem.querySelectorAll('div.errors, ul.errorlist').length === 0) {
                if (elem.classList[3] != 'start-open') {
                    elem.classList.add('collapsed');
                }
                const h2 = elem.querySelector('h2');
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.id = 'fieldsetcollapser' + i;
                link.className = 'collapse-toggle';
                link.href = '#';
                if (elem.classList[3] != 'start-open') {
                    link.textContent = gettext('Show');
                } else {
                    link.textContent = gettext('Hide');
                }
                h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ('));
                h2.appendChild(link);
                h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(')'));
            }
        }
        // Add toggle to hide/show anchor tag
        const toggleFunc = function(ev) {
            if (ev.target.matches('.collapse-toggle')) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                ev.stopPropagation();
                const fieldset = ev.target.closest('fieldset');
                if (fieldset.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
                    // Show
                    ev.target.textContent = gettext('Hide');
                    fieldset.classList.remove('collapsed');
                } else {
                    // Hide
                    ev.target.textContent = gettext('Show');
                    fieldset.classList.add('collapsed');
                }
            }
        };
        document.querySelectorAll('fieldset.module').forEach(function(el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', toggleFunc);
        });
    });
}
```